# Change the color or the progress bar indicator in the beamer metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes, beamer-metropolis

I am trying to find (without success) a way to change the orange color of the progress bar indicator in the beamer metropolis theme. Are you aware of the command that I should use for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default colour used for the progress bar is

```
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{%
  use=alerted text,
  fg=alerted text.fg,
  bg=alerted text.fg!50!black!30
}
```

The `fg` value defines the already presented part, the `bg` value the part to come.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
42
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
42
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your preamble you can change the color with the command

```
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{ ... }
```

See the documentation in chapter `3.2`

http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/doc/metropolistheme.pdf