# Progress bar and sections/subsections

Tags: beamer, sectioning, themes

After my reading of a nice topic [Progress bar for latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59742/progress-bar-for-latex-beamer) on progress bar, I want to know if it is possible to do a progress bar which take into account all the whole slides and also the number of slides in the current subsection.

To be more precise, I would like a very simple progress bar as in [Change the color or the progress bar indicator in the beamer metropolis theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413760/change-the-color-or-the-progress-bar-indicator-in-the-beamer-metropolis-theme), but when we can distinguish the different subsection. The aim of this is to allow people to know where we are in the subsection and in the entire presentation.

To be more precise with what I imagine, the principle would be the same as the one with the circle progress bar, you can tell how many slides remains in the current subsection and in the entire presentation. So I would like to do the same but with a progress bar, maybe by adding some vertical bars indicating the limits between the differents sections (subsections).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but for the simple case that you don't use overlays, maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{mysub}
\AtBeginSubsection{\addtocounter{mysub}{1}\label{mysub:\themysub}}
\newcounter{foo}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (\thepage/\insertdocumentendpage*\paperwidth,0);
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{mysub}}{%
            \setcounterpageref{foo}{mysub:\x}
                \draw[thick] (\thefoo/\insertdocumentendpage*\paperwidth,0) -- (\thefoo/\insertdocumentendpage*\paperwidth,0.5);    

        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{document}

\section{section name}
\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{section name}
\subsection{section name}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]